# C#, instantiating a generic type - with variable type argument?

Tags: c#, generics

Code example:

```
void Foo(params object[] objects)
{
    var entries = new List<IEntry>();
    foreach(var o in objects)
    {
        var entry = new Entry<o.GetType()>(); // this doesn't work
        entries.Add(entry);
    }

    ...
}

Foo("hello", 5); // should fill entries with Entry<string> and Entry<int>
```

Why is that not possible? I guess I need to work with reflection instead? How to do that properly AND performant?

Comment: Is this the best practice: `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (Entry<>).MakeGenericType(o.GetType()));` ?

Comment: Since you're treating the object as non-generic IEntry anyway, why use generics at all?

Comment: This is just for the moment, later on a user can determine the generic argument with the IEntry.Type property. Doesn't sound nice to you I guess, however, I can't give all the context.

Comment: How many arguments are there - could you provide an overload for each length? See for example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.create.aspx

Comment: You mean "arguments to Foo"? The number is arbitrary.

Comment: Can you make `Entry` non-generic and pass `o.GetType()` as a constructor argument?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I can't change the signature of `Foo` and can't change `Entry` either. Looks like I'm stuck with my reflection approach. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Unless someone tries to cast an IEntry to a Entry<T>, you could simply define a new class that implements IEntry. No need to change the signature of Foo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just can't use C# generics the way you're trying to do in your snippet.

In order to use [C#] generics, the actual object type **must be known at compile time**.

You're trying to dynamically pass the object type as a type parameter. This is simply not possible.

**Edit**

Yes, it is possible to dynamically create generic objects using reflection. After all, generics is implemented both as a compile-time C# construct and as a .NET framework feature (as opposed to, say, Java, where it is only a compile-time feature based on Type Erasure). So, in .NET, through reflection, it is possible to implement the latter "bypassing" the former (which, again, would be impossible in Java).

But the OP clearly does not need that.

After all, `entries` is a `List<IEntry>`. IOW, the `entries` container **does not "know" the concrete type of its elements** (since it is bound to an interface). So, if each element to be add already implements `IEntry`, then this would be enough:

```
void Foo(params IEntry[] objects)
{
    var entries = new List<IEntry>();
    foreach(var o in objects)
    {
        entries.Add(o);
    }

    ...
}
```

OTOH, if those objects do not implement `IEntry`, then the OP just need a pure, ordinary, old-school list of untyped objects:

```
void Foo(params object[] objects)
{
    var entries = new List<object>();
    foreach(var o in objects)
    {
        entries.Add(o);
    }

    ...
}
```

So using reflection in order to dynamically create a generic container, even if possible, seems to be overkill for this particular use case.

Comment: @siride: in what way does reflection contradicts what I said about **generics**....?

Comment: @tEsTA, the problem is that using reflection to inject the type argument into `Entry<>` *is using generics*.  As far as the CLR is concerned it's the same as if the compiler did it.  The utility of doing so is difficult to judge without more context.

Comment: @KirkWoll: "is using generics". In a way, yes. I could even use `Reflection.Emit`, and generate generics byte code at run time. In your opinion I believe it would also "be the same". But my point is precisely that it is not: In order to **properly use C# generics** (which is something that the OP, it seems, doesn't know how to do), we must first learn how to do that without "cheating". C# is a statically typed language, and so type parameters must be resolved in compile time. That's what I mean by "C# Generics", and that's why I'm saying that using reflection is far from being the same thing.

Comment: In other words: when we are using reflection, we are "beyond" C#. We are dealign directly with the .NET virtual machine. Since generics are also present in the VM, one may believe generics in C# and in the .NET VM are "one and the same". They are not. It would be perfectly possible to have statically typed generics in C# and **not** having generics support into the .NET virtual machine (and that's exactly what happens with Java, by the way).

Comment: @tEsTA, as I said before, I do not believe there is enough info provided by the OP to determine whether using reflection for generics here is useful; though given his comments I presume so.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with reflection

```
var entryType = typeof(Entry<>);
Type[] typeArgs = { o.GetType() };
var genericType = entryType.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
IEntry entry = (IEntry)Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
```

Comment: First, I won't downvote you (I already gave an alternative answer). Second, you code is correct. But I don't think this really helps the OP: he seems to be trying to use generics for an use case which generics is **not** needed, and you're trying to make he use reflection just in order to make generics work (and imho you fail, since creating "generic objects" by reflection is far from being the same thing as properly using C# generics).

Comment: @tEsTA, there is nothing about this answer that "fails" the question posed by the OP.  There are times when using reflection for generics like this is exactly what is needed, and without more context from the OP there is no way to judge whether this solution doesn't suffice.

Comment: @KirkWoll: I don't think you really understood what I said. Again: creating generic arguments with reflection is **not** the same thing as properly using C# generics. Yes, sometimes, somewhere, somehow this is useful. Doesn't seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 1):

You need a function of the form:

```
Func<Type, IEntry>
```

I would suggest adding a static function to the parent of Foo like this:

```
public static IEntry Make(Type type)
```

Inside that function, feel free to add whatever code makes sense to you:

```
if (type == typeof(string))
{
    return new StringEntry(); //Obviously some special logic based on the type.
}
else
{
    //Default logic
    return (IEntry) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Entry<>).MakeGenericType(type));
}
```